# SSH AUTHENTIFACTION ISSUE

Tags: sshd, archlinux-arm

I am a newbie to embedded networking. I want to set arm board as a ssh server .From other boards(client boards connected in the network), I need to connect to this server board.

I have downloaded the `openssh` and cross compiled it for arm successfully. 
I have used default `sshd_config` file  and run sshd command in arm-board.

Command

```
"ssh-keygen -t rsa -f /usr/local/etc/ssh_host_rsa_key -N "" "
```

is used to genrate key.

My doubt is where can I set the username and password, so that I can login from a remote client using ssh command. I didn't find any document regarding this...?

Comment: Unfortunately this question isn't directly related to programming and is off-topic for [SO]

Answer (score 0):

Using ssh you are logging in as a normal system user. So you should add user using `useradd` command. You can change password using `passwd` command.